# angular ui grid single click with editableCellTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm having trouble getting angular ui grid to enter editing mode in a cell on a single click only when im using a cellTemplate/editableCellTemplate. Here is a plunker that demonstrates the code i have currently and the problem i'm having. If you click on the cell under hte Name column, you will notice it is single click, but the cell under the Type column is double click, needs to be single click.

Steps to reproduce:

1. click on the cell under the ID column
2. click the cell under the name column (notice edit is on single click!)
3. click the cell under the id column again or in the white space of the grid/or off the grid
4. click on the cell under the type column (should be single click to edit mode, requires double click)

[working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NlSpTHwufZm2Ru5XVIQ9?p=preview)

```
`var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit',` 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize', "ui.grid.pagination", "ui.grid.edit", "ui.grid.cellNav", "ui.grid.selection", "ui.grid.pinning"]); //draggableRows?

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        excludeProperties: '__metadata',
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        useExternalSorting: true,
        useExternalFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            name: 'id',
            enableCellEdit: false,
            width: '10%',
            pinnedLeft: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            enableCellEdit: false,
            displayName: 'Name',
            width: '20%',
            pinnedLeft: true,

        },
        {
            name: 'type',
            displayName: 'Type',
            enableCellEdit: true,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
            cellEditableCondition: true,
            cellTemplate: 'passFailTemplate.html',
            editableCellTemplate: 'editablePassFailTemplate.html',
            width: '70%'
        }
    ];

    $scope.load = function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = [{
            "id ": "1",
            "name": "2.03",
            "type": "Needs to be Single CLick to edit here",
        }]
    };
    $scope.load();
}]);
```

...see plunker

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: It takes a double click to enter editing in the cell. Needs to be single click to edit

Comment: [the doc](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable) says it should be double click - _Editing is invoked via **double-click**, f2, or start typing any non-navigable key. Cell editing ends on tab, enter or esc (cancel) on an input editor, and tab, left or right arrows, enter or esc for a dropdown._

Comment: I updated plunker to better show the problem, with ui-grid-cellNav you can single click to edit cells, but it doesnt work for the Type column, only works on the Name column

Comment: @Boutin actually for me working for single click only...

Comment: see steps to reproduce..

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. In fact, the Type cell is only editable after you have clicked on the Name cell, regardless of clicking under Id.